# How to specify parts using the ruby aws-sdk multipart_upload method

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The [ruby aws-sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#multipart_upload-instance_method) specifies in the following example that someone can upload a file in multiple parts:

```
bucket.objects.myobject.multipart_upload do |upload|
  upload.add_part("a" * 5242880)
  upload.add_part("b" * 2097152)
end
```

But what is "a" and "b"? 
Are they files? 
And if they are files, how is the file seperated in parts to upload? Do we have to do that seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a" and "b" is only used for creating two strings that are used as dummy data. "a" is copied 5242880 times to a large dummy string.

Multipart_upload is for uploading multiple parts if the same file. In this case the parts will be saved in myobject.

So an example for uploading two part of a file.

```
bucket.objects["my_new_file.doc"].multipart_upload do |upload|
  upload.add_part(File.read("local_file.doc", 1000)) # first 1000 bytes
  upload.add_part(File.read("local_file.doc", 1000, 1000)) # next 1000 bytes
end
```

Consult the documentation for add_part on how you can pass on files or content: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/MultipartUpload.html#add_part-instance_method.

Comment: Sorry, but even after reading the link above, I still don't get it. If I want to upload a file that is for example 7654321 bytes long in chunks of 1000 bytes, each chunk separately, and adding :part_number , how would I do that?

Comment: Ok, didn't see that 1000, 1000 is part of File.read and not add_part method.

Comment: @GiannisNohj Thats correct. File.read("local_file.doc", 1000, 1000) reads 1000 bytes starting from offset 1000.